# Is a closed subset of a locally compact Hausdorff space is compact?

Tags: general-topology

Hi everyone: We know that closed subsets of a compact (Hausdorff) space are compact. What if the space is just (Hausdorff) locally compact?

Comment: How about trying an example?  $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.  Does it have closed subsets that are not compact?

Comment: (1).$\mathbb R$ is locally compact Hausdorff. Any unbounded closed subset (e.g $\mathbb N$ ) is non-compact. The whole space is a non-compact closed subset.... (2). Any infinite set with the discrete topology is locally compact Hausdorff. Any infinite subset of it is closed and non-compact.... (3). However a locally compact Hausdorff space is a Tychonoff space.

Comment: I think it is a good question. I had the same doubt. Since space X has a one-point compactification Y, any closed set in Y is compact. However, the subtlety consists in that a closed set in X is not necessarily closed in Y.